# Pass a function and attribute when i call a component

Tags: angular, components, parent-child

I have a component call like this

```
<app-sidebar
[onClick]="closeIt(checkbox)"
></app-sidebar>
```

And in the sidebar component i want a function that execute the closeIt(checkbox) function, so i can use it from the html file of the sidebar component.

How can I do this?

I tried like this but it doesn't even compile cause i don't know what to put as an argument in onCloseClick.

In my sidebar component

```
  @Input()
  onCloseClick: (args: any) => void;

 closeSidebar(): void {
    this.onCloseClick()
  }
```

Is it a good starting point or i have to change something?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to pass a function, so you can call it later you need to pass the function itself, like this:

```
<app-sidebar
  [onClick]="closeIt"
></app-sidebar>
```

this way you pass the function, and not calling the function.

Besides that, when you declare this function you decide whether to pass an argument or not, so check there if you need it and what the type of it is, so you can call it from inside. If you don't need it, simply remove it.